# Не работают медиа запросы

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, mobile

Не могу понять, почему не работает медиа запрос. Проверяю с помощью инструментов веб-разработчика в firefox. В гугле искал, ничего похожего не нашел. Вот код html.

```
<p>Большой текст</p>
```

Код css.

```
p {
color:black;

font-size: 80px;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 590) {
p {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Так ведь max-width неправильный.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавить `px`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 590px) {
```